# log_errors_max_len = 1024 in php.ini, but php log keeps growing

Tags: permissions, php, logfiles, maxlength

As the title says, I've set the max length for the php error log, but it seems to keep growing much much larger than 1024.  I am using the correct php.ini, I've restarted apache, etc.  The permissions on the php log are 666.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, does this directive configure the total length of the file (which makes little sense, as the default value is 1024 bytes), or only the maximum length of one entry / one line ?

Comment: There are several `php.ini` configuration parameters that work together in a somewhat non-intuitive way. On your system, what are the values of `log-errors` http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.log-errors and `error-log` http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-log ?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As is typical for PHP, it is not really obvious from the name of the configuration setting, or even the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.log-errors-max-len), but this directive applies to the length of a *single log message*, not the length of the log file as a whole.

Use logrotate or a similar tool for what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 10):

Verified [Pascal's initial thought](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966540/log-errors-max-len-1024-in-php-ini-but-php-log-keeps-growing#comment1880387_1966540):

> [log_errors_max_len](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.log-errors-max-len)  integer
>
> Set the maximum length of log_errors
>   in bytes. In error_log information
>   about the source is added. The default
>   is 1024 and 0 allows to not apply any
>   maximum length at all. **This length is
>   applied to logged errors, displayed
>   errors and also to $php_errormsg.** When
>   an integer is used, the value is
>   measured in bytes. Shorthand notation,
>   as described in this FAQ, may also be
>   used.

Comment: that documentation is clearly incorrect.  log_errors is a boolean, so "maximum length of log_errors" is nonsense.

Comment: @Adrien file a bug

Answer (score 8):

What the manual doesn't state is that [`log_errors_max_len`](http://php.net/log_errors_max_len) refers **only** to the "body" of the error message. This means that a single line of error **will still be greater** than the length you set here.

To demonstrate, run this code using `log_errors_max_len=0` (`0` means unlimited) and [`log_errors=1`](http://php.net/log_errors):

```
<?php
// Set your server to these settings:
// error_reporting=-1 
// date.timezone=utc ;to suppress the error message "It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings."...
echo$msg1; echo$msg2;
```

The bytes sent to [`error_log`](http://php.net/error_log) will be:

```
[15-Jul-2015 01:23:45 utc] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: msg1 in C:\index.php on line 5
[15-Jul-2015 01:23:45 utc] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: msg2 in C:\index.php on line 5
‏
```

Next, test the same code with `log_errors_max_len=4` and `log_errors=1`. (Remember to restart the server.) `error_log` will now be:

```
[15-Jul-2015 01:23:45 utc] PHP Notice:  Unde in C:\index.php on line 5
[15-Jul-2015 01:23:45 utc] PHP Notice:  Unde in C:\index.php on line 5
‏
```

(Notice that your error message is prepended with "`[15-Jul-2015 01:23:45 utc] PHP Notice:`" and appended with "`in C:\index.php on line 1`", resulting in a line longer than what is set by `log_errors_max_len`.)

This issue occurs not just with `error_log`, but also with the server output sent to the client. To demonstrate, run the same code above using `log_errors_max_len=4`, [`display_errors=1`](http://php.net/display_errors), [`html_errors=0`](http://php.net/html_errors), [`error_prepend_string="PPPP"`](http://php.net/error_prepend_string), and [`error_append_string="AAAA"`](http://php.net/error_append_string). The output sent to the client is:

```
PPPP
Notice: Unde in C:\index.php on line 5
AAAAPPPP
Notice: Unde in C:\index.php on line 5
AAAA
```

Now run the same code using `log_errors_max_len=4`, `display_errors=1`, **`html_errors=1`**, `error_prepend_string="PPPP"`, and `error_append_string="AAAA"`. (`error_prepend_string` and `error_append_string` apply only to displayed errors, not logged errors.) The output sent to the client is:

```
PPPP<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Unde in <b>C:\index.php</b> on line <b>5</b><br />
AAAAPPPP<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Unde in <b>C:\index.php</b> on line <b>5</b><br />
AAAA
```

Also note that the above tests would return the same results even if you use [`ignore_repeated_errors=0`](http://php.net/ignore_repeated_errors). This shows that "repeated errors" are considered **before** the error messages are cropped.

(Your results may differ depending on the SAPI used. Above tests are done using php-5.6.7-Win32-VC11-x86 CLI on win 8.1.)