# ebs volume on ec2 gets exhausted by htttpd access_log and error_log

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, httpd.conf

how do i put a limit on the file size for files in 
`etc/httpd/logs`

every time i remove those files to free up my space, they come back after 1-2 weeks and take up the entire EBS volume space

Answer (score 1):

The best thing to do is to use **log rotation**. You can swap out the log files hourly or daily, then delete the older ones.

With Apache you can use the [rotatelogs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/rotatelogs.html) program. Most Unix operating systems also have something like [logrotate.d](http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/understanding-logrotate-utility), which can easily be configured to rotate and then delete.

Comment: what about the `log_errors_max_len` setting in `/etc/php.ini`? I set it to 1024. Shouldn't that have worked to tackle the problem?

Comment: That's for [the maximum length of a single line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966540/log-errors-max-len-1024-in-php-ini-but-php-log-keeps-growing).